# HTTP Error 400 Bad Request when trying to search for tweets using urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, urllib

I need to use `urllib` for Python 3 in order to get search tweets from Twitter API (please do not recommend another library).

I was able to get the access token from Twitter. But I am having difficulty using search tweet API using this token.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

SEARCH_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"
headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + oauth2["access_token"],
            "Content-Type" : "application/json" }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': '#archaeology'}).encode('utf-8')
my_request = urllib.request.Request(SEARCH_URL, data=data, headers=headers)
with request.urlopen(my_request) as resp:
    tweets_in_bytes = resp.read()
```

I am getting a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` message on the `request.urlopen(my_request)` part. What am I doing wrong? I am using Python v3.7.3.

Comment: Looks to me like your headers aren't right. Have you tried changing your "Bearer: " section - the double quotes together ("") look dodgy

Comment: @HaydenEastwood That's not an issue, I used the exact same thing when trying to retrieve the token and it worked. I removed that as well, as you suggested, same result.

Comment: @oikonomiyaki are you sure the bearer token format matches what twitter expects? try to print(headers).

you can leave the `+ ""` out by the way, that just adds a empty string to the end, which does absoluetly nothing.

Comment: @laundmo Amended the question, I have removed that already. Same result.

Comment: @oikonomiyaki did oyu confirm that if you print(headers) its still correct?

Comment: @laundmo Yes, same thing. That empty string inside double quotes has no bearing.